# Jquery Datatables Scroller Plugin in full height

Tags: jquery, scroll, datatables

is it possible to use the scroller plugin of datatables for a datatable which fills 100% of the screen height?

```
   $("#testtable").dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": sLoc +'/Test/getData',
        "sServerMethod": "POST",
        "bScrollInfinite": true,
        "sScrollY":"200px",
        "sDom": "frtiS",
        "oScroller": {
            "loadingIndicator": true
        }
    });
```

if i change the sScrollY Option here to something other than 200px the scrollbar disappears. If i change also the iDisplayLength value it seems to work. Is there a feature to find out how many entries could fit on the actual page?

It makes no sense to load all the data if i want to use infinite scrolling. But if i load to less the scrollbar is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did it this way :

first i calculated the page height and subtracted the height of the datatable specific div tags.

```
$(".page").height()     - $(".dataTables_filter").outerHeight(true)
                        - $(".dataTables_scrollHead").outerHeight(true)
                        - $(".dataTables_info").outerHeight(true);
```

Then i set this value for `$("div.dataTable_scrollBody").height()`

For me this is a acceptable workaround and perhaps it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is as follows..

```
var calc_datatable_height = function() {
  return Math.round(jQuery(window).height() - [some offset for headers etc]);
};
```

In the table setup

```
scrollY: calc_datatable_height(),
```